# Get the correct days in a specific month in 2014 javascript

Tags: javascript, date, object

I have a problem with getting the correct days for each month in year 2014.. 
It shows that January and February has 31 days each, and March 28.
Im unable to fix this. Maybe you can come up with some tips or tricks? :)

EDIT:
I can see that my programme first month == 0 is collecting from december year 2013 which is very wierd, because i only refer to 2014 in the "Date" function. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Here is my code:
The months and the days are in swedish, but I dont think that will be a problem..

```
function DaysInAMonth (month) {
return new Date(2014, month, 0).getDate();
}

function nameOfTheWeekdays(day) {
return [
"Måndag", "Tisdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lördag", "Söndag"
][day];
}

function getMonthName(month) {
 return [
 "Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
][month];
}

var month = 0;
var day = 0;

for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
for (var x=0; x<DaysInAMonth(i); x++) {

var c = new Date(2014, i, x);   

document.writeln( nameOfTheWeekdays(c.getDay()) + " " + (x+1) + " " + getMonthName(month)); 


day++;

}

month++;
}
```

Comment: You could probably do to learn about the [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: ... or JavaScript arrays

Comment: @Pointy Them too. It's easier if you use fixed-length abbreviations, because then you can do haxy stuff like `"SunMonTueWedThuFriSat".substr(dow*3,3);` :p

Comment: Your "DaysInAMonth()" function is now broken because you fixed the month counter. It should be `new Date(2014, month + 1, 0).getDate()`

Answer (score 4):

Months in JavaScript dates are numbered 0 through 11, not 1 through 12. Indeed, your "DaysInAMonth()" function seems to rely on that fact.

The date 1 January 2014 is obtained from `new Date(2014, 0, 1)`.

You can use an array to map month or day numbers into names:

```
function getMonthName(m) {
  return [
    "Januari", "Februari", "Mars", "April",
    "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "Augusti",
    "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"
  ][m];
}
```

Comment: Okey, will try to put the months in an array and the days... 
But how will it help to get the right day on january 1st?

Comment: If you construct the date properly (`new Date(2014, 0, 1)`) you'll get the right day.

Comment: i get the right date now :) 
But a new problem showed up.. my first month is dec 2013, but i want jan 2014... really strange

Comment: @user3428781 ?? `new Date(2014, 0, 1)` is "01 Jan 2014"